# getCurrentLocation() method in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

While I am trying to implement a simple example getting the location of the device, I found that a document which is "seemingly official": https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current#BestEstimate

The document claims that `FusedLocationProviderClient` provides the following two methods: `getLastLocation()` and `getCurrentLocation()`. But as one can see in the example - https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current#last-known - both `getLast/CurrentLocation()` lives in Java. The corresponding Kotlin example says that `fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()` "is the same as" `fusedLocationClient.lastLocation` and, indeed, it works well.

I naively assume that there should be corresponding "`currentLocation`" for example, `fusedLocationClient.currentLocation`.

I am wondering there is no such, or I am the only one who fails to find the corresponding Kotlin method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in kotlin any method of the form `getX` can be written as just `x`, this is called "property access syntax". There is no separate kotlin version. `fusedLocationClient.lastLocation` is really exactly the same as `fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()`. You can even write this last form in kotlin if you want.

However, this is only true for "get" methods without parameters. The thing is, `getCurrentLocation` does have parameters so property access syntax is not possible in this case. as you can see [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient#public-tasklocation-getcurrentlocation-int-priority,-cancellationtoken-token) this is the signature of this method:

```
public Task<Location> getCurrentLocation (int priority, CancellationToken token)
```

So you should use it like that. for example

```
fusedLocationClient.getCurrentLocation(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, null)
```

EDIT:

apparently `null` as parameter is not allowed. According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/72159436/1514861 this is a possibility:

```
fusedLocationClient.getCurrentLocation(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, object : CancellationToken() {
            override fun onCanceledRequested(p0: OnTokenCanceledListener) = CancellationTokenSource().token

            override fun isCancellationRequested() = false
        })
        .addOnSuccessListener { location: Location? ->
            if (location == null)
                Toast.makeText(this, "Cannot get location.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            else {
                val lat = location.latitude
                val lon = location.longitude
            }

        }
```

Comment: Great! Thank you for your answer.

Comment: null is not a valid argument for this function, can you update a workaround ?

Comment: a good example can be found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72159435/how-to-get-location-using-fusedlocationclient-getcurrentlocation-method-in-kot

Answer (score 1):

```
fusedLocationClient.getCurrentLocation(Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, object : CancellationToken() {
        override fun onCanceledRequested(listener: OnTokenCanceledListener) = CancellationTokenSource().token

        override fun isCancellationRequested() = false
    })
    .addOnSuccessListener {
        if (it == null)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cannot get location.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        else {
            val lat = it.latitude
            val lon = it.longitude
        }

    }
```