# How to get location using "fusedLocationClient.getCurrentLocation" method in Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-location, kotlin-android

To request the last known location of the user's device, we can use the [fused location provider](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current) to retrieve the device's last known location using `getLastLocation()`, but using `getCurrentLocation()` gets a refresher, and more accurate location.

so, how to use the `fusedLocationClient.getCurrentLocation()` in Kotlin as there is no example illustrated in the documentation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient#getCurrentLocation(int,%20com.google.android.gms.tasks.CancellationToken)), the `getCurrentLocation()` takes two parameters.

The **1st** parameter it takes is the **priority** (e.g. `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY`) to request the most accurate locations available, or any other priority that can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest#constant-summary).

The **2nd** parameter it takes is a **cancellation token** that can be used to cancel the current location request.

From the Google play services [reference](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/CancellationToken), a `CancellationToken` can **only** be created by creating a new instance of CancellationTokenSource.

so here is the code you need to use when using `getCurrentLocation()`

```
class YourActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout)

        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)

        fusedLocationClient.getCurrentLocation(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, object : CancellationToken() {
                override fun onCanceledRequested(p0: OnTokenCanceledListener) = CancellationTokenSource().token

                override fun isCancellationRequested() = false
            })
            .addOnSuccessListener { location: Location? ->
                if (location == null)
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Cannot get location.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                else {
                    val lat = location.latitude
                    val lon = location.longitude
                }

            }

    }
}
```

Comment: what is `CancellationToken`?

Comment: How can addOnSuccessListener return an empty location? I don't understand that. If it's a success, then there should be always a location. How can this be retried?

Comment: As you can see from this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current#last-known) that the location object may be null in the following situations:

1- Location is turned off in the device settings because, disabling location also clears the cache.
2- The device never recorded its location (e.g. new device or a device that has been restored to factory settings).
3- Google Play services on the device has restarted, and there is no active Fused Location Provider client that has requested location after the services restarted. @Houman

Comment: Use `Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY` instead of deprecated `LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY`.

Comment: working except getCurrentLocation() error, Unresolved reference: getCurrentLocation

Answer (score 4):

I know the question is about Kotlin but I want to add for those searching for **Java**, based on [this example in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current#java):

```java
CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
fusedLocationClient.getCurrentLocation(Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, cancellationTokenSource.getToken())
.addOnSuccessListener(MyActivity.this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Location location) {
        // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
        if (location != null) {
            //do your thing
        }
        Log.w(TAG, "No current location could be found");
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually it's not that rare that this returns null. Why does this happen?

Comment: Not helpful but this is what [the docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient#getCurrentLocation(com.google.android.gms.location.CurrentLocationRequest,%20com.google.android.gms.tasks.CancellationToken)) have to say about `null` being returned : "Returns a single location fix representing the best estimate of the current location of the device. This may return a historical location if a recent enough location fix exists, or may compute a fresh location. If unable to retrieve a current location fix, null will be returned."

Answer (score -1):

```
fusedLocationClient.getCurrentLocation(Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, object : CancellationToken() {
    override fun onCanceledRequested(listener: OnTokenCanceledListener) = CancellationTokenSource().token

    override fun isCancellationRequested() = false
})
.addOnSuccessListener {
    if (it == null)
        Toast.makeText(this, "Cannot get location.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    else {
        val lat = it.latitude
        val lon = it.longitude
    }

}
```